# Widespread American Minhag

Tags: minhag, chutz-laaretz

What is the single most widely practiced *minhag* (religious Jewish practice that's not mandated by *halacha*) among Jews in the United States today? By "widely practiced" I mean practiced by the most people.

Comment: Do you mean any religious Jewish practice that's not mandated by strict Halacha? Do you mean versino of prayers?

Comment: I mean the former.

Comment: The truth is that this is an amazing question, as many people confuse Minhag and Halacha. I am taking a stab at the answer, however I would not be surprised if I am incorrect.

Comment: Is this question limited only to the US or to all of Chutz L'Aretz?

Comment: I only had the US in mind. But I'm sure a question about Chutz La'Aretz in general could be interesting.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/what-is-the-most-widespread-israeli-minhag?rq=1

Comment: is this a riddle?

Comment: No, I really wanted to know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hands down it is  - not saying Birchas Kohanim on a daily basis

Comment: Great answer! Even completely unaffiliated Jews do this. <wry smile>

Comment: But the sephardim don't do this (i.e. they say birkat kohanim).

Comment: @Chanoch, true, but, alas, something unaffiliated and Reform Jews do outweighs by far what religious _S'faradim_ do with respect to "most widely practiced".

Comment: Although the Sefardim do say Birchas Kohanim there are way more Ashkenazim in the diaspora than Sefardim

Comment: Gershon, I think that we all say it on a daily basis, we just don't duchan daily :)

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two questions here:

- What custom is most widespread among observant American Jews that is less common in other countries?
- Name something post-Talmudic that most American Jews, observant or not, keep.

For the latter category, I think we could point to the Jewish customs of mourning, which are observed overwhelmingly across the spectrum of observance.  Most notably, saying Kaddish!  (Post-Talmudic.)

For a custom that is, let's say, post-Shulchan Aruch, I would say covering the mirrors in a shiva house.  Some say this was simply a matter of covering the mirrors in rooms where prayers would be held (we don't pray facing a mirror), but Rabbi Joseph Dov Soloveichik argued that this was a version of a Talmudic custom regarding repositioning all the beds in the house -- they're both ways of expressing the loss of humanity experienced.

Comment: I've been in Shiv'ah houses - even Orthodox ones - in which mirror were not covered. It surprises me every time I encounter it, but I don't believe the custom is as widespread as you believe it is.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78764/13438

Answer (score 4):

Are we including *minhage sh'tus*? How about gift-giving on *Chanuka*?

---

*Edit:* See [`https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3572`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3572) — apparently it might not be a *minhag sh'tus*.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping Yomtov Sheini, which now that we have a set calendar is only an obligation due to ***minhag*** avoseinu. **Yet, it still has the full force of mandated *halacha*.** (Thank you Shalom!)

Comment: But has the full force of Rabbinic law

Comment: Shalom, true. A very important distinction. I did not read the question very well.

Comment: L'havdil, the Reform got rid of y"t2

Answer (score 3):

Yizkor is a big one.

Comment: However it is also done in Eretz Yisroel and all other countries. The question is widespread American Minhag

Answer (score 2):

I'd bet it's the Pesach Seder.

Comment: You mean the aspect of the "seder" that is exactly 15 rhyming steps long? Many parts of it, after all, are mitzvos.

Comment: Sitting down for a meal on Pesach night and calling it a Seder.

Comment: I think eating a meal on _yom tov_ is a matter of _halacha_, no? or do you mean only the calling-it-_seder_ part?

Comment: Most steps of the seder are mandated by halacha. I bet you could only find a couple parts (like the song) that weren't mandated by halacha.

Comment: @Chanoch - IIRC, me'ikar hadin, the only things that must be said aloud at the seder are "pesach" "matzah" and "maror".

Answer (score 2):

Well one I can think of offhand is reading the Haftorah on Shabbos. But I'm sure there are plenty more.

Comment: Most Jews in the US have probably never heard of a Haftarah, ba'avonoteinu harabim.

Comment: It's not necessarily the majority of U.S. Jews who are the significant sample here. It's the largest set of U.S. Jews adhering to the same minhag. There must be better statistical terminology to describe this distinction.

Comment: More to the point, reading the haftarah is also required by halachah. Maybe you mean "reading the same haftarah" (since, most weeks, almost all minhagim do use the same section)?

Comment: Halacha? But it was started because there was once a decree that we couldn't read the Torah...

Comment: True, but it remained as halachah afterwards (see commentaries to Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 284:1).

Comment: @yydl The same Avudraham who brings down that reason brings down the completely unrelated (apparently legal) reason that it's a "step down" from k'ri'as haTorah to the d'rasha that does not constitute a hefsek in davening.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15677/759

Answer (score 2):

Celebrating (purposely using very vague term), wrongly (Halachicly) or rightly Yom Kippur.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: They recognize some significance to the day

Comment: Attending "services".

Answer (score 1):

What about candle lighting 18 minutes before sunset?

Comment: Many Chasidim light 15 minutes before sunset and many others light 20 minutes before sunset

Comment: Reform Judaism doesn't necessarily maintain that kabbalat shabbat is taluy on shkiat hachammah. (and by extension, Reform Jews, a majority of American Jewry)

Answer (score 0):

Blowing Shofar in Elul is a Minhag which I think all follow.

Comment: It's not universal among sephardim - though many have minhagim to blow the shofar in conjunction with selichot, there are many who do not have a minhag to blow at all in Elul.

Answer (score 0):

Bathing on Friday.

> מצוה על כל אדם לרחוץ בכל ערב שבת פניו ידיו ורגליו בחמין. ואם אפשר,
>   ירחץ כל גופו בחמין.‏

קיצור שולחן ערוך, סִימָן ע"ב, סעיף י"ב

Comment: Laafukei Isreal?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not touching that one.

Comment: But isn't that essential to this being an answer? It can't be a universal practice like: waking up.

Comment: @DoubleAA, fine. North Americans, including (especially?) Jews, have a reputation, as opposed to their peers in Europe and the Middle East, of being hygienically meticulous. Hence, this is the only custom I can think of that might rival [Gershon Gold's example](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3568/5).

Comment: @DoubleAA, What about sleeping extra?