# Mezuzah for room used by Non-Jews

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mezuzah

In a Jewish-owned and -operated mifa'al (factory/business), there is a room that is designated for the non-Jewish workers where they can eat, rest, etc. The room is used for nothing else (not even for storage purposes). Does the room need a mezuzah?

Comment: pretty sure it does. what establishes the requirement is the fact that a Jew owns the building, I think

Comment: Hi YMW and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  This seems to fit better as a comment than an answer, though if you can expand on it or bring a source please do post an answer.  I look forward to seeing you around the site.

Comment: Yehoshua, would you please [edit into the question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/19085/edit) your reason for mentioning _eretz Yisrael_, for assuming that that's relevant?

Comment: @msh210 Perhaps related to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16249/what-halachot-does-an-american-traveling-to-israel-have-to-be-made-aware-of/16250#comment44595_16250

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.hasofer.com/page.pl?p=attach#Doors) site gives some excellent information about mezuzot and is worth browsing through. As you can see, from the part of it that I linked to, a room needs a mezuzah so long as it is either owned or rented by a Jew, whether or not it is a room in which people dwell.

The book reviewed [here](http://torahmusings.com/2012/08/book-review-inside-stam-a-complete-buyers-guide/), by Rabbi Reuvain Mendlowitz, looks to contain a lot of excellent information on the question that you have asked as well, and will be available shortly.