# Can a pedestrian cause a Jewish driver to stop for him to cross the road on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, eretz-yisrael, heterodox, vehicles-transportation

In many places Israel [to date], cars are driven by Jewish drivers.[presumably Tinokot Shenishbu]

When crossing the road in Israel on Shabbat :

Can one do so in a way that the driver has to slow down/stop in order for you to cross or must you wait until the car passes and only then cross.

If. in general, you must wait for the car to pass: what if he has already stopped and is waiting for you to cross - must you still wait for it to pass or can you cross?

Would there be a distinction between crossing at a specially marked pedestrian crossing which by law - cars have to stop there for pedestrians to cross, or crossing in a place where pedestrians aren't supposed to cross.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16250/128 (where it's listed - currently as #9)

Answer (score 2):

I can't fully answer the question, but I do remember a story:

A Jew who was driving once stopped a great Rav (I'm sorry that I don't remember who) walking to shul on Shabbos, and asked for directions. The people walking with the Rav expected him to berate or at least ignore the driver, but instead the Rav gave him very exact and detailed directions.

After the person drove away he explained to them that at least this way he would minimize his driving, and thus his chillul shabbos.

Presumably the same applies here: Do your best to minimize how much the other person violates shabbos.

Comment: WADR that story sounds apocryphal unless you can source who the Rav is

Comment: Related http://torahmusings.com/2013/01/directions-on-shabbos/

Comment: As mentioned in the article linked by @DoubleAA , the p'sak behind the story is factual. However, this does not answer the question. In many cases, the best way the avoid affecting the other person's use of their car is either to pretend that you are not going to cross until after they leave the intersection or to quickly cross behind their car.

Comment: @Fred OK, so if that's the best way, then that's what you should do. Why do you imply that that's a contradiction?

Comment: @Ariel I'm not saying there's a contradiction, but the question was along the lines of: "Must you avoid actions that will lead them to violate Shabbos at a slightly different time and in a slightly different way that presumably involves greater Shabbos violation than otherwise?" Your answer is basically "yes", but your story does not show that you are required to do so; the story involves a direct action to minimize *chilul Shabbos* as opposed to inaction, whereas the case in the OP involves action (e.g. going to a crosswalk) that would increase *chilul Shabbos* versus inaction that would not.

Comment: Peninei Halakha ([here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-26-09/#_ze05ftn26_9), footnote 9) quotes a similar psak in the name of R Shlomo Zalman Auerbach