# Mezuzah on rental property

Tags: halacha, transactions, mezuzah, real-estate, rental

If you own a home that you rent out, are you obligated to place a Mezuzah (or Mezuzoth) on that property?

What if the property is attached to your home, such as a basement apartment or add-on suite?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16250

Comment: Is the tenant Jewish?

Answer (score 3):

The *Mishneh Torah*, in [*Hilkhot Tefilin u-Mzuzah ve-Sefer Tora* 5:11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2305.htm#11), says( see also [*Shulchan Arukh*, *Yoreh De'ah* 291:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&pgnum=231)):

> המשכיר בית לחברו--על השוכר להביא מזוזה ולקבוע אותה, אפילו היה נותן שכר על קביעתה:  מפני שהמזוזה חובת הדר היא, ואינה חובת הבית

[In English](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925427/jewish/Chapter-Five.htm):

> When a person rents a dwelling to a colleague, the tenant is obligated to obtain a *Mezuzah* and affix it. [This applies] even if he would pay to have it affixed. [The rationale is] that a *Mezuzah* is an obligation incumbent on the person dwelling [in the house], and is not incumbent on the house

I would say that the same would apply to the attached property( such as a basement apartment or add-on suite).