# most neglected positive mitzvah?

Tags: mitzvah, mussar-ethics

In the context of a [discussion](https://www.ou.org/torah/parsha/rabbi-weinreb-on-parsha/rabbi_weinrebs_torah_column_parshas_emor/) of the obligation of burying a corpse found on the way:

> And an exception is made for the met mitzvah. Should the kohen
>   encounter an abandoned corpse, and no one else is available to bury
>   it, he is commanded to ignore the prohibition against contact with the
>   dead, and he must bury that corpse himself.

One commentary (don't have it handy sorry) linked it to performing mitzvot that are neglected (i.e., 'dead' to most Jews/people). There are Mitsvot that has no one to "support them" like a corpse that has no one to bury it.

I enjoyed this idea and wondered how to put it in practice.
Could someone tell me how to do so?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3529

Comment: Techeles. .....

Comment: Can this question be answered objectively?

Comment: @IsaacMoses why not? For example, concerning Lo Taasse there are mitsvot that people trample on them. Rabenu Yona in Shaare Teshuva has some Mitsvot. The topic is very classical.

Answer (score 3):

R Norman Lamm (in a 1965 [typeset *dvar Torah*](http://brussels.mc.yu.edu/gsdl/collect/lammserm/index/assoc/HASH9068.dir/doc.pdf) !, see also [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/machshava-from-ou/rabbi-lamm-women-tefillin/)) mentions the source as being the Vilna Gaon (p. 7). He applies it (*pp. 8ff*) to *tsedaka* and gives examples such as lending money with no interest, not feeling bad about giving money, mishloach manot (well, that changed!) then shatnez, shaving, rising in front of the elder, minha in a *mynian*, *tzniut*. That shows how much the answer to your question changes with time !

I am not aware of any more recent "official source" but I could list a number of rare mitzvot that few of us get a chance to perform

- [Redeeming a firstborn's donkey](http://www.shturem.org/index.php?section=news&id=52570)
- [Peah](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah216/): leaving the corner of a field for the needy
- [Leket](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah218/): leaving gleanings in the field
- [Sending away a mother bird to take her eggs](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah545/)
- [Unloading an animal](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah541/)
- [Yibbum](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah598/): levirate marriage (marrying the wife of a brother who deceases without children)
- [Chalitzah](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah599/): a special ceremony when a man refuses to marry his deceased brother's wife who has no children
- [Burying someone on the day of his execution](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah537/)

Here is a [full list](http://www.jewishcontent.org/general/positive.htm) of positive mitzvot if interesting to a reader of the question.

Comment: Do not we have unloading an animal by physicaly helping someone who can't do by himself (or is that dirabonon?

Comment: @hazoriz few of us have the opportunity to practice it because few of us meet loaded animals having masters who cannot load/unload them. At least where I live I don't often meet loaded animals

Comment: Does this mitzva not include thing that you do see often?

Comment: @hazoriz not me but I guess that is the limitation of the question which is quite dependent on the time (see my edits at beginning of my answer) and on the individual

Comment: Burying someone on the day they died applies to everyone and it is regularly followed.

Comment: Do you know lots of people who were obligated in Chalitza and neglected to perform it?

Comment: I am not sure if the woman is not interested in marrying again if it still has to be performed.

Comment: You could add writing a sefer torah.  Now it is commercialised they have"groups" for this and the pidyon chamor.

Comment: @newcomer I thought of it but so many people buy letters (w/ some ruling it is equivalent to writing a sefer Torah) that I felt it wasn't so rare anymore

Comment: Well people buy peter chamor as well.  It is not so simple because a kohen must not be one of them. And you cant be sure it wont be a female. @mbloch

Comment: @mbloch humans are animals too. you've never met someone carrying a heavy bunch of groceries who needed help?