# Jewish source for giving Chanuka gifts

Tags: chanuka, sources-mekorot, gifts

Is there a Jewish source for Chanuka gifts?

Comment: @SimchasTorah - Is he referring to gelt or gifts?

Comment: Referring to gifts

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Emes Leyaakov on Shulchan Aruch on Siman 670, Reb Yaakov says that giving gifts on Chanukah is not Chukas Hagoyim, it is a Jewish Minhag and they took it from us. The reason for it is that they sent a gift with the children to the Rebbeim, and the children got gifts too because they were the shluchim. A much earlier sefer, Chanukas Hatorah, a sefer the Magen Avraham quotes in Hilchos Chanukah, speaks of giving Chanukah GIFTS.

Comment: do you have an exact page/siman in the Chanukas Hatorah ? I would like to look it up.