# Is the Haftarah a Minhag?

Tags: minhag, halacha-theory, haftarah

Is reading the Haftarah a Minhag?

I know that the practice was instituted when we couldn't publicly read torah, and then it was kept. Does that make it a Minhag?

Comment: I'd guess no, cuz it has it's own beracha and we generally refrain from making berachot on minhagim (consider "chavit chavit **velah barich**" on hoshana rabba)

Comment: I assume you're asking about reading the haftarah, which (as I understand it) was originally done at a time when we weren't permitted to publicly read torah?

Comment: @Monica Cellio. I think it added was when the Romans banned torah study.

Comment: @Daniel Lee. They couldn't have been added before we got the torah because the texts are taken from neviim and ketuvim which were written long after we got the torah. We couldn't have read them before they were written.

Comment: @AriA Greeks (well, Syrian-Greeks), not Romans.

Comment: i think a followup question, inspired by a comment above is, considering the origin of reading haftorah, what is the nature of the brachot we say before and after. none is on a mitzvah of reading of nevi'im, but about equating the nach section with the torah section or which discusses why we set a day aside to be mekadeish god.

Comment: Daniel, I've edited your question to make it a little clearer.  If I have misunderstood your intent please roll back my edit.

Comment: @Dan I could be wrong, but from the text of the birkot hatorah before and after leining, they don't seem to be on a mitzvah either. Not only that, but they actually parallel the brachot on the haftorah pretty nicely. The first brachot are both about hashem choosing people (bnei yisrael/neviim) and the second brachot both mention the fact that Hashem's word (the torah/the words from the neviim) is true.

Comment: @AriA - a couple of thoughts -- the first is that there is already a body of writing about the exact nature of birchot hatorah and what they "accomplish" (and whether they are on a mitzvah) but I was simply commenting on the assertion that we don't make a bracha on a minhag (hotly contested) and avoiding the question by saying that the bracha wouldn't be on elevating the status to a mitzvah. second, the text seems to be parallel to and replacing birchot hatorah since the haftarah reading replaced the laining.

Comment: @Dan are berachot on minhagim really controversial? I thought it was pretty clear from hatavat aravot (probably our oldest minhag) that we don't do it. Perhaps though those are only "Asher kidishanu..." berachot.

Comment: all I know is what I read on the internet http://www.torahmitzion.org/eng/resources/show.asp?id=717 tells of why we would not make on, while apparently the shulchan aruch says we do make one in shul on channukah candles though the lighting is a minhag. There are enough webpages and shiurim on the topic to convince me that the answer is not simple.

Answer (score 4):

משנה ברורה  in ס' רפד ס'ק ב says that it began as a custom to say when public torah reading was banned, and was subsequently enacted as a גזרה. This would appear to be backed by earlier authorities, as רמ'א quotes תשובות הרמב'ן in that סימן describing the 'תקנה' of הפטרה, as opposed to just a מנהג.