# Covering the mirrors in the house of a mourner

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, mourning-aveilus, provenance

When learning the laws of mourning in the Gemara and rishonim I don't recall the requirement to cover up the mirrors in the house of a mourner. But it does seem like a quite prevelalant practice. Where did this practice begin and what is the reason for doing so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zvi Ron wrote an [entire article](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol13Ron.pdf) about this in Ḥakirah (vol. 13).

To quote and summarize: the earliest source is the Hattam Soffer (19th century) [i]:

> He explains that mirrors were turned around to face 
>   the  wall  based  on  the  mourning  practice  of kefiat  hamittah,  overturning  the  beds.  The  Babylonian  Talmud  (Mo‘ed  Katan
>     15b)  gives Bar Kappara’s reason for this practice. Man was created in the image of God; because of human sin resulting in death this Divine image is 
>   ‘overturned.’  To  represent  this  idea  we  overturn  our  beds.  The Jerusalem Talmud (Mo‘ed Katan
>    3:5) gives another reason. The marital bed is the facilitator for relations between husband and wife to create  new  life. This  facilitator  is  overturned  when  a  life  has  ended.
>
> Hatam Sofer explains that although we no longer practice the overturning  of  beds, the  reasons  given  in  both  Talmuds  apply  to  mirrors  as  well.  Mirrors  contain  the image  of  the  person  looking  into  them, so mirrors are turned around because the Divine image in the 
>   deceased  has  been  ‘overturned.’  Additionally,  Rashi  (Ex.  38:8)  explains  that  in  Egypt  mirrors  facilitated  relations  between  husband  and  wife,  just  like  the  beds.  Therefore  the  mirrors  are  turned  around  in  a  house  of  mourning,  just  as  beds  were  overturned  in Talmudic times.

R. Aharon
 Ziegler reports in 
the  name  of  R.  Soloveitchik  th
at  the  connection  between  overturned beds and mirrors is that both act as reminders that intimate 
relations are suspended during the 
shivah;
 furthermore, mirrors are 
an 
expression  of  vanity  and  should  not  be  used  in  a  house  of  mourning [ii]

A variety of other explanations have been proposed, such as mirrors bringing joy, mirrors being covered to facilitate prayer in their presence, avoiding seeing evil spirits that lurk in the house of the mourner.

Particularly this last reason which associates reflective surfaces with spirits; particularly of the dead, seems to have been a fairly common non-Jewish idea. Indeed, even the practice of covering the mirrors was practiced by gentiles, although sometimes without connecting it to this reason.

Thus, decades before the earliest mention of the practice in Jewish literature, we find funerals in Scotland being described [iii]:

> I know not for what  reason  they  lock  up  all  the  cats  of  the  house,  and  cover  all  looking glasses as soon as any of the family dies, nor can they give any  satisfactory  account  of  it

Similarly, reflective surfaces were covered for President Lincoln's funeral:

> The  East  Room,  in  which  the  remains  were  laid, was decorated in mourning... the windows at either end of the room were draped with black barege [a sheer fabric], the frames of the mirrors...being  heavily  draped  with  the  same  material. [iv]

Even earlier, in 1841, we find the same thing upon the death of President Harrison. [v]

Fascinatingly, This  custom  to  cover  mirrors  after  a  death  occurs  is  found  all  over  the  world,  including  the  places  where  all  the  earliest  Jewish  references  to  the  custom  originated,  Hungary, Romania  and  Transylvania.

Besides  the  countries already mentioned it has been documented in places as diverse as  the  Dominican  Republic, England, China, India  and Madagascar.

While today a popular Jewish custom, R.  Moshe  Tzuriel,  has  written  that  this  is  an  inappropriate  custom  and  should  be  discontinued. [vi]

---

[i] Hatam  Sofer:  Derashot (New  York:  Avraham  Yitzchak  Friedman, 1961)  vol.  2,  p.  774.

[ii]       R. Aharon Ziegler, 
Halakhic Positions of Rabbi Joseph B. Soloveitchik 
(New 
Jersey: Jason Aronson, 1998) p. 122

[iii] History  of  Orkney
  (Kirkwall:  Orkney  Heritage  Society,  2001),  p.  55.

[iv]     William  T.  Coggeshall,  The  Journeys  of  Abraham  Lincoln  (Columbus: Ohio State Journal, 1865) p. 110.

[v]     Claire A. Faulkner, “Arlington’s Ceremonial Horses and Funerals at the White House”, White House History 19, p. 23.

[vi] Otzrot  ha-Torah  (Bnei  Brak:  2005)  vol.  2,  p.  1017.

Comment: +1. Any idea whether _Chasam Sofer_ is recommending it, saying it's the common practice, or both?

Comment: @msh210 Ron's understanding is that "This led him to provide meaningful Jewish reasons for practices that were observed at the time by religious Jews, even when they originated from local folklore or historical circumstances," I would take that as a limmud zekhut for a seemingly strange practice. More of a justification of a common practice, than an explicit recommendation. That is Ron's view IIUC. It seems very reasonable to me.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=489

Comment: @GershonGold Nice find. Was there some particular point mentioned there not found in my answer?

Comment: @mevaqesh: Not that I noticed. Just figured it may be helpful for some in Hebrew, therefore attached as comment.