# Covering pictures in the house of a mourner

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, mourning-aveilus, pictures

There is a minhag I have heard of where in addition to [covering all of the mirrors](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78762/covering-the-mirrors-in-the-house-of-a-mourner?rq=1) in the mourner's house they would also cover all pictures of the deceased. I have long tried to find a source for this minhag, and eventually I did find a sefer discussing it, though I can't find that sefer anymore. Has anyone else heard of this minhag, and where it might be sourced?

It does not seem to be because the pictures are shiny and could be like mirrors, because all pictures would then be covered, and pictures that are not in frames shouldn't be.

Comment: http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=18305

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rabbi Oshinski in his sefer Hilchos Aveilus (Perek 3:24) he writes (bringing the Zichron Eliyahu and the [Pnei Baruch](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47632&pgnum=139)) that mirrors are covered and some hold that pictures are covered as well. He does note from others that covering picture may only be an issue when people are praying the shmoneh esrei.

Text of sefer:
[image]